# How do you write more than 1 line in an if statement in Haskell

Tags: if-statement, haskell, compiler-errors

I have an if-else statement, and in the else block I want it to first recurse to the function, except for the last two elements of the list, and then return two elements.

In the following function, after the if-else statement, I have 2 lines of code. however this doesnt compile. I believe the compiler reads these two lines as a single line of code. How do you fix that?

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer] --outputs the input list, but every 2nd element(from the right) is doubled
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther x = if (length x <2)
                        then
                            x
                        else
                            doubleEveryOther init (init x) -- These two lines
                            [2*last(init x), last x]       -- These two lines
```

The compiler says:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type: [Integer]
                  with actual type: [a0] -> [a0]
    * Probable cause: `init' is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of `doubleEveryOther', namely `init'
      In the expression: doubleEveryOther init (init x)
      In the expression:
        [doubleEveryOther init (init x), 2 * last (init x), last x]
   |
19 |                             [doubleEveryOther init (init x), 2*last(init x), last x]
   |
```

Comment: It makes no sense to do that: you return the result of a function call. What would be the meaning of these two items?

Comment: It's not an `if` *statement*; it's a conditional expression. Haskell doesn't *have* statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an if-else statement, and in the else block I want it to first
> recurse to the function, except for the last two elements of the list,
> and then return two elements

OK. I sort of understand what you're doing. The function name is good - the best name is `verb-noun`, here `doubleEveryOther`. However, the code looks a lot like Lisp, probably Scheme - the repeated use of `init` gives it away. That's not how you write Haskell. (I also write Lisp in Haskell syntax too much...)

Haskell recursion works using pattern matching.

```
lst = [2,3,4]
1 : [2,3,4]   -- [1,2,3,4]

lst = [1,2,3,4]
(x:xs) = lst  -- x is 1, xs = [2,3,4]
```

So, in this case, you want to match your list against `x:y:xs`:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
(x:y:xs) = lst  -- x is 1, y is 2, xs=[3,4]
```

Hence:

```
doubleEveryOther :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther [x] = [2*x]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:xs) = (2*x):doubleEveryOther xs
```

Please note the number of special cases which need to be handled. If I am given an empty list, I should return an empty list. If I am given a single value, I need to double it (in analogy to your if .. else clause). If I am given two or more values, this matches x=first, y=second, xs=[] or more.

As for returning more than one value, you can return only one thing from a function. It can be a single value, a single tuple, a single list, and so on.

In this case, you have written a function which says `doubleEveryOther` - good - but then you want to return the last two values unchanged. You would be better taking off the last two values, running the simple `doubleEveryOther` and then bolting the last two values on the end. Otherwise, you are overburdening your function.

Comment: `init` isn't really how you'd write it in Scheme either, to be fair.

Comment: @amalloy: it's the fine-detail feeling to the code. In a lot of Scheme code there's a lot `car` and `cdr` - here, `last` and `init`. I also wonder if there is a list comprehension solution to the problem, or something like that.

Comment: There can't be any solution using just a list comprehension (i.e. of the form `doubleEveryOther xs = [...]`), because that's equivalent to just `map` and `filter`, but we need to treat elements non-uniformly. But you can do it by zipping with a list of functions, which gives you the extra information you need.

Comment: @amalloy : Something like `[2*x | (x,keep) <- zip [1,2,3,4] (cycle [True,False]), keep]`

Comment: I think you have missed what the question asked for. We want `doubleEveryOther [1,2,3,4]` to be `[1,4,3,8]` (or maybe `[2,2,6,4]`?), not `[2,6]`.

Comment: I wanted `doubleEveryOther [1,2,3,4]` to output `[2,2,6,4]`. However This answer is still mostly valid, because it shows what I have to do to get my answer, which is pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just missing the append operator `++`:

```
doubleEveryOther (init (init x))
  ++ [2 * last (init x), last x]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not return two lists. If you have two results you want to combine, you use some function, like `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

That being said, you here don't need this. You can work with simple pattern matching:

```
doubleEveryOtherFromLeft :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleEveryOtherFromLeft (x:y:xs) = 2*x : y : doubleEveryOtherFromLeft xs
doubleEveryOtherFromLeft xs = xs
```

then our `doubleEveryOther` can reverse the list twice:

```
doubleEveryOther:: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleEveryOther = reverse . doubleEveryOtherFromLeft . reverse
```

Comment: What would in particular be important to note is that `recursive ++ suffix` makes the whole thing quadratically complex in the input length. This should never be used unless you're sure that the input is always very small.